# How to navigate into other divs and access their contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image][image]

I want to to navigate from the `#toDoListContainer` div into the `#taskDiv`, how do I do this in jquery.

I want to navigate from div to div to be able to access the data of each div to get the picture to appear

I did the command

```
console.log($("#toDoListContainer")[0]);
```

so i was trying to navigate the div like this..

> `console.log($("#toDoListContainer")[0].children);`

I should be able to get into the zeroth div by doing:

> `console.log($("#toDoListContainer")[0].children[0]);`

but I get undefined instead. any Ideas ?

Comment: [0] is the DOM node of the jQuery object. You likely want `.eq(0)` - also IDs need to be unique. Change to class and grab them with `.taskDiv` which you can navigate in a loop. Lastly post CODE instead of pictures of code in a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: What does .eq do? And what is the zero for

Comment: Collections and arrays are 0 based in JavaScript. Please read the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: I vote to close: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: First things first, IDs should always be unique. You should never have same IDs. Instead, you should be using class. Secondly, always share the code and not the screenshots.

Comment: You should post your whole code on JSFiddle so other can preview the result.

Comment: @RidoanSalehNasution or just click the `<>` snippet editor button here

Answer (score 0):

Hey change your ids to class like this because
Id should be unique.

```js
$('#toDoListContainer').find('div.taskDiv').each(function() {

  var self = $(this);
  // now what ever you want to do
  //like 
  console.log(self.attr('data-completed'));
  console.log(self.text())

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toDoListContainer">
  <div class="taskDiv" data-completed="y">text1</div>
  <div class="taskDiv" data-completed="y">text2</div>
  <div class="taskDiv" data-completed="y">text3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed them to classes and copy pasted ur code but nothing happened

Comment: Of course I do  that's what I been running my whole program

Comment: Please check again its working for me with some changes

Comment: Why find? `$("#toDoListContainer .taskDiv")`

Answer (score 0):

Using same Id for all your divs is bad practice, you're not respecting the [HTMl Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10) which says that ID must be unique for an element in the whole page

So change you id to class, and it can be accessed directly

See below snippet :

```js
$(function(){
  $("#toDoListContainer .taskDiv").each(function(index,element){
    
    console.log("task n°"+index+ " data-completed = "+$(element).data("completed"));
    console.log("it's HTML Content = "+$(element).html());
    console.log("--------------------------------------");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toDoListContainer">
  <div class="taskDiv" data-completed="Y"><p>paragraph</p></div>
  <div class="taskDiv" data-completed="Y"><span>span</span></div>
  <div class="taskDiv" data-completed="N"><h3>heading text</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: does this help you !

Comment: I will try it when I get home, is there a way where I can post like my whole project folder instead of just snippets?

Comment: yes you can create poject  in plaunker , just create file and paste your code , here is its link :) , [plaunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: the `<>` snippet editor here works just as well for such code

Comment: Also why find? `$("#toDoListContainer .taskDiv")`

Comment: yes , you're right   @mplungjan , also thnx for edit :)

Comment: @MoisesMiguel is this what you where trying to do or not :)

Answer (score -2):

It is not recommended to have same id for multiple elements but still if you want to keep HTML code as it is following snippet can help.

```js
var taskDivs = $("div #taskDiv");
taskDivs.each(function(x) {
  console.log(taskDivs[x])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toDoListContainer">
  <div id="taskDiv"> Task 1 </div>
  <div id="taskDiv"> Task 2 </div>
  <div id="taskDiv"> Task 3 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to explain the reasoning behind your answer. How is it different from what is asked? How can you iterate? Snippet of it.